# Cordova plugin geolocation for android doesn't return altitude

Tags: android, ionic-framework, geolocation, cordova-plugins, altitude

I am currently trying to obtain the altitude of a phone running Android 5.1.1 but it doesn't seem to get it. I'm using the cordova plugin geolocation on the ionic platform which allows you to use AngularJS. The weirdest part is the phone gets the right latitude and longitud coordinates but it receives an empty field in altitude.

My code is the following one:

```
 $ionicPlatform.ready(takeCoordinates);
```

`function takeCoordinates() {
    var watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function (position) {
      $scope.geoPosition.lat  = position.coords.latitude;
      $scope.geoPosition.long = position.coords.longitude;
      $scope.geoPosition.alt  = position.coords.altitude; 
      }
    );`

Do you have any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Have you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `enableHighAccuracy: true`

Comment: Yeah, I tried with true and false and nothing worked.

Comment: Can you specify exact use case of altitude in your application?

Comment: you are testing outside so the gps has a chance of getting a good fix?